# Drawing double lines using pseudo elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I need to draw the double lines under my paragraph using pseudo elements only, but I should not use display block as per the specifications given to me. Can anyone help in this. Below is my code (using display block):

```css
p:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  height: 7px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The box-sizing Property</h1>
<p>Defines how the width and height of an element are calculated: should they include padding and borders, or not.</p>

<h2>box-sizing: content-box (default):</h2>
<p>Width and height only apply to the content of the element:</p>
<div id="example1">This div has a width of 300px. But the full width is 300px + 20px (left and right border) + 60px (left and right padding) = 380px!</div>

<h2>box-sizing: border-box:</h2>
<p>Width and height apply to all parts of the element: content, padding and borders:</p>
<div id="example2">Here, the full width is 300px, no matter what!</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are pseudo-elements, not pseudo-classes. Just like how your HTML tags are elements, not classes.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have made the edit to my question. Any advice on my query?

Comment: Use `display: inline-block;` instead.

Comment: Doesn't the spec given to you provide any reason for such a strange limitation? What could be wrong with `display:block` for `::after`?

Comment: The reason is to use minimum lines of code to achieve the desired results. Also they want me to use other options apart from using display properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` on `p` element instead.

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
p:after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  height: 7px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The box-sizing Property</h1>
<p>Defines how the width and height of an element are calculated: should they include padding and borders, or not.</p>

<h2>box-sizing: content-box (default):</h2>
<p>Width and height only apply to the content of the element:</p>
<div id="example1">This div has a width of 300px. But the full width is 300px + 20px (left and right border) + 60px (left and right padding) = 380px!</div>

<h2>box-sizing: border-box:</h2>
<p>Width and height apply to all parts of the element: content, padding and borders:</p>
<div id="example2">Here, the full width is 300px, no matter what!</div>
```

Or you can use `absolute/relative` positions with `transform: translateX`.

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

p:after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  height: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -7px; 
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>The box-sizing Property</h1>
<p>Defines how the width and height of an element are calculated: should they include padding and borders, or not.</p>

<h2>box-sizing: content-box (default):</h2>
<p>Width and height only apply to the content of the element:</p>
<div id="example1">This div has a width of 300px. But the full width is 300px + 20px (left and right border) + 60px (left and right padding) = 380px!</div>

<h2>box-sizing: border-box:</h2>
<p>Width and height apply to all parts of the element: content, padding and borders:</p>
<div id="example2">Here, the full width is 300px, no matter what!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only restricted with `display:block` use `display:table` instead:

```css
p:after {
  content: "";
  display:table;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  height: 7px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The box-sizing Property</h1>
<p>Defines how the width and height of an element are calculated: should they include padding and borders, or not.</p>

<h2>box-sizing: content-box (default):</h2>
<p>Width and height only apply to the content of the element:</p>
<div id="example1">This div has a width of 300px. But the full width is 300px + 20px (left and right border) + 60px (left and right padding) = 380px!</div>

<h2>box-sizing: border-box:</h2>
<p>Width and height apply to all parts of the element: content, padding and borders:</p>
<div id="example2">Here, the full width is 300px, no matter what!</div>
```

Or make it `inline-block` with 100% width and instead of border use linear-gradient to create both lines:

```css
p:after {
  content: "";
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#000,#000) 50% 0%/40px 1px no-repeat,
             linear-gradient(to right,#000,#000) 50% 100%/40px 1px no-repeat;
  height: 9px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The box-sizing Property</h1>
<p>Defines how the width and height of an element are calculated: should they include padding and borders, or not.</p>

<h2>box-sizing: content-box (default):</h2>
<p>Width and height only apply to the content of the element:</p>
<div id="example1">This div has a width of 300px. But the full width is 300px + 20px (left and right border) + 60px (left and right padding) = 380px!</div>

<h2>box-sizing: border-box:</h2>
<p>Width and height apply to all parts of the element: content, padding and borders:</p>
<div id="example2">Here, the full width is 300px, no matter what!</div>
```